# Disabling Juniper Services

Tags: devops, juniper, juniper-network-connect

I currently am running a juniper firewall that I would like to disable some services that are not considered best practice. Does there happen to be any specific commands using Juniper's CLI to disable FTP and disable Telnet?

Answer (score -1):

delete groups global system services telnet
delete groups global system services ftp
(they should not be enabled by default; as you eluded to, both are insecure)